# URL not outputted when using Axios npm package

Tags: node.js, axios

I'm using nightwatchjs with the [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) npm package to test that a large list of URLs return the correct status code.

My code looks like this;

```
var axios = require('axios');

module.exports = {
    '@tags': ['siteMapTesting'],
    'Sitemap test for Parkers pages': async (browser) => {
        var result = await alasql.promise('select URL from xlsx("./testUrls.xlsx",{sheetid:"QA-245-xmlSiteMap"})');
        var xcelData = result.map(item => {
            return item.URL;
        });
        async function siteMapUrlsTestArr(item) {
            var response = await axios.get(browser.launch_url + item);
            console.log('Sitemap test URL =', (browser.launch_url + item + '  status code = ' + response.status));
            browser.verify.equal(response.status, 200);
        }
        for (let index = 0; index < 1000; index++) {
            var xmlTestUrl = xcelData[Math.floor(Math.random()*xcelData.length)];
            await siteMapUrlsTestArr(xmlTestUrl);
        }
    },
    'Closing the browser': function (browser)  {
        browser.browserEnd();
    },
};
```

This works fine when the URL returns the expected 200 status code.

However, when it fails, it fails with the following message;

> Site Map/ QA 245 Xml Site Map] Sitemap test for Parkers pages (556ms)
> AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404
> at BrotliDecompress.emit (node:events:525:35)
> at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
>
> ---
>
> TEST FAILURE: 1 error during execution; 0 assertions failed, 1 passed
> (4.029s)
>
> ✖ siteMap/QA-245-xmlSiteMap  – Sitemap test for Parkers pages (556ms)
>
> AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404
> at BrotliDecompress.emit (node:events:525:35)
> at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
>
> SKIPPED:
>
> - Closing the browser

As can be seen, there is no mention of the tested URL that caused the failure, so I have no idea which of the 1000 randomly selected URLs has returned a status code other than a 200.

I'd like to `console.log` the URL and the status code, but still making sure the test fails with a 404, 500, etc status code.

I've also tried adding a loop into the test script, as below;

```
var alasql = require('alasql');
var axios = require('axios');

module.exports = {
    '@tags': ['siteMapTesting'],
    'Sitemap test for Parkers pages': async (browser) => {
        var result = await alasql.promise('select URL from xlsx("./testUrls.xlsx",{sheetid:"QA-245-xmlSiteMap"})');
        var xcelData = result.map(item => {
            return item.URL;
        });
        async function siteMapUrlsTestArr(item) {
            var response = await axios.get(browser.launch_url + item);
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                throw new Error('Sitemap fail URL =', (browser.launch_url + item + '  status code = ' + response.status));
            }
        }
        for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
            var xmlTestUrl = xcelData[Math.floor(Math.random()*xcelData.length)];
            await siteMapUrlsTestArr(xmlTestUrl);
        }
    },
    'Closing the browser': function (browser)  {
        browser.browserEnd();
    },
};
```

but this doesn't list the failing URL either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, not long after posting (sorry!).

This worked for me;

```
var alasql = require('alasql');
var axios = require('axios');

module.exports = {
    '@tags': ['siteMapTesting'],
    'Sitemap test for Parkers pages': async (browser) => {
        var result = await alasql.promise('select URL from xlsx("./testUrls.xlsx",{sheetid:"QA-245-xmlSiteMap"})');
        var xcelData = result.map(item => {
            return item.URL;
        });
        async function siteMapUrlsTestArr(item) {
            axios.get(browser.launch_url + item)
            .catch(function (error) {
                if (error.response) {
                    console.log(item, error.response.status);
                    throw new Error();
                }
            })
        }
        for (let index = 0; index < 500; index++) {
            var xmlTestUrl = xcelData[Math.floor(Math.random()*xcelData.length)];
            await siteMapUrlsTestArr(xmlTestUrl);
        }
    },
    'Closing the browser': function (browser)  {
        browser.browserEnd();
    },
};
```